# Pass nested array to Symfony Form for EAV type table

Tags: arrays, rest, api, symfony, validation

Take this request data:

```
HTTP PUT
[
    'id' => 1,
    'company' => 'Company Name',
    'attributes' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'url',
            'value' => 'example1.com'
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'url',
            'value' => 'example2.com'
        ],
    ]
]
```

I want to build a form that validates `attributes` using choice loaders:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

    $builder->add(
        $builder->create('attributes', FormType::class, [
            'compound' => true
        ])
    );

    $builder->get('attributes')
        ->add('attribute', ChoiceType::class, [
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank([
                    'message' => 'attribute name cannot be blank.'
                ])
            ],
            'choices' => [
                'url',
                'type',
                'email',
                'date',
            ],
        ])
        ->add('value', TextType::class)
    ;
}
```

However when i write my unit test for this:

```
public function testAttributesForm(array $data)
{
    $form = $this->factory->create(AttributesType::class);
    $form->submit($data);

    if(!$form->isValid()) {
        var_dump($form->getErrors()->current()->getMessage());
    }
 }
```

I get a failed validation:

`string(42) "This form should not contain extra fields."`

Which is because it finds a nested array instead of the actual fields.

**How do I pass nested data in a way where I can fully use validation constraints?**

In the past I used `CollectionType::class` with `'allow_add' => true` but it doesn't allow for very detailed validation.

Answer (score 1):

You should try use directive

```
'allow_extra_fields' => true
```

Comment: this will suppress errors when adding extra forms/fields, but won't help with actual validation.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to validate nested data without a `data_class` using Forms (as you may when writing an api) you need to add a form per **collection** dynamically, in this case:

The first form builder method would look like this:

```
class CompanyType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('id', IntegerType::class)
            ->add('company', TextType::class)
        ;

        $builder->add(
            $builder->create('companyAttributes', CollectionType::class, [
                'allow_extra_fields' => true
            ])
        );
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'csrf_protection' => false,
        ]);
    }
}
```

and the second would also be a standalone form:

```
class CompanyAttributeType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('value',TextType::class)
            ->add('attribute',TextType::class, [
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank([
                        'message' => 'Parameter name cannot be blank.'
                    ])
                ],
            ])
        ;
    }
}
```

When the request is sent, you would create the first and add the second form in a loop.
Notice  the loop's `$key` is used for the form name so you can do `$form->get(1)` etc.

```
$form = $this->factory->create(CompanyType::class);

if(!empty($data['attributes'])) {
    foreach ($data['attributes'] as $key => $parameters) {
        $form->get('companyAttributes')->add($key, CompanyAttributeType::class);
    }
}

$form->submit($data);
if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    //2xx response
} else {
    //4xx/5xx response
}
```

This setup will validate all forms when `$form->submit($data)` is called.